# Is `String::with_capacity()` equal to `malloc`?

Tags: memory-management, rust

I read [this article](https://www.reddit.com/r/unix/comments/6gxduc/how_is_gnu_yes_so_fast/?st=j3v3iw3c&sh=5651ea3c) a few days ago and I thought what is the best way to implement such a thing in Rust. The article suggests to use a buffer instead of printing the string after each iteration.

Is this correct to say `String::with_capacity()` (or `Vec`) is equal to `malloc` in C?

Example from the codes:

```
String::with_capacity(size * 4096)
```

equal to:

```
char *buf = malloc(size * 4096);
```

Comment: Why do you post this code ? Your question don't need that, no ? The article too don't deserve the question.

Comment: They're definitely not equal, but I'd like to understand what kind of answer you are looking for. Can you please quote the minimal relevant parts from that article and code snippet?

Comment: @Stargateur hmm, I just wanted to make a clear question. Do you want me to remove the link?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani This is your question.

Comment: Yiour llink is meaningless, starting with the first sentence: 'Compared to other Unices, GNU is outrageously fast.' The GNU C and C++ compilers are not implementations of Unix.

Comment: Well, I really want to know why this question is "off-topic"? This is just my question and I suppose this could be the question of many other beginners in Rust.

Comment: Remove your project and the article: your question "Is `String::with_capacity()` equal to `malloc`?" make sense. Don't need the context.

Comment: Personally, I don't agree with the close vote. Right now the minimal pieces of code necessary are there. Eventually, the reason for the down-vote could be lack of effort: if you searched other resources before asking, the question does not show that.

Comment: @E_net4 I see, I tried to search for a few hours but I do see what you mean. I will take your advices into account for the next questions, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not "equal", Rust's `String` is a composite object; `String::with_capacity` creates a [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/collections/string.rs.html#263-265) which is not only a buffer; it is a wrapper around a `Vec<u8>`:

```
pub struct String {
    vec: Vec<u8>,
}
```

And a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/collections/vec.rs.html#356-361) is not just a section in memory - it also contains a `RawVec` and its length:

```
pub struct Vec<T> {
    buf: RawVec<T>,
    len: usize,
}
```

And a [`RawVec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/raw_vec.rs.html#47-50) is not a primitive either:

```
pub struct RawVec<T> {
    ptr: Unique<T>,
    cap: usize,
}
```

So when you call [`String::with_capacity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/collections/string.rs.html#395-397):

```
pub fn with_capacity(capacity: usize) -> String {
    String { vec: Vec::with_capacity(capacity) }
}
```

You are doing much more than just reserving a section of memory.

Comment: Perfect, this answer clarifies my question, thanks. Then, what is the best or the most accurate way to achieve something like `malloc` in Rust? (excuse me for expanding my question with a comment)

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani Most likely, you don't want to do that. If you just want a byte buffer, `Vec` is fine. For implementing low-level data structures, one can use unstable APIs such as [`allocate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/heap/fn.allocate.html).

Answer (score 3):

That isn't quite accurate. It'd make more sense to say `String::with_capacity` is similar to `std::string::reserve`. From the documentation:

> Creates a new empty String with a particular capacity.
>
> Strings have an internal buffer to hold their data. The capacity is
>   the length of that buffer, and can be queried with the capacity
>   method. This method creates an empty String, but one with an initial
>   buffer that can hold capacity bytes. This is useful when you may be
>   appending a bunch of data to the String, reducing the number of
>   reallocations it needs to do.
>
> If the given capacity is 0, no allocation will occur, and this method
>   is identical to the new method.

Whether or not it uses something similar to `malloc` for managing the internal buffer is an implementation detail.

In response to your edit:

You are explicitly allocating memory, whereas in C++ a memory allocation for `std::string::reserve` only occurs if the argument passed to `reserve` is greater than the existing capacity. Note that Rust's `String` *does* have a `reserve` method, but C++'s string does not have a `with_capacity` equivalent .

Comment: But I thing the OP want to compare with C not C++. Your answer is off topic. "is equal to malloc in C?"

Comment: @Stargateur Rust's `String` is similar to C++'s `std::string`. There is no similar construct in C, so such a comparison would be meaningless.

Comment: So "This isn't accurate" (translation: no) followed by what it's actually more similar to doesn't answer the question? Good to know.

Comment: @Stargateur We can not be entirely sure whether that is true without improvements to the question. So far, this answer has shown to be of good quality and to address the question in its literal sense. And that is certainly on-topic, even with a chance of the question having a different intent.

Comment: @E_net4 The OP **clearly** say "is equal to malloc in C?", what is not clear for you ? Imagine with this logic I could make a answer that compare with haskell... This answer would be perfect if the OP want a comparison with C++.

Comment: The question could ask if it's equal to Trump's haircut. My answer would still be the same. The obvious intent of the question is to achieve a similar effect to malloc; however, I point out that malloc does not behave the way they expect it to. A more analogous approach would to get a pointer to uninitialized memory, however one would do that in Rust.

Comment: Arguably, the differences between C's `malloc` and C++'s `malloc` are minute and irrelevant in this context. And since C can not reproduce the automatic memory management mechanisms found in C++ and Rust, providing examples in C++ is easier. But sure, a C counterpart could be considered. _On the other hand_, not having one isn't enough of a reason to make it off-topic or not an answer, according to SO standards.

Comment: @user8193326 thanks for this answer, helped me to understand the context but I can only accept one answer. cheers.

Comment: @Stargateur : The only people capable of asking a perfect question are those who already know the answer – one **must** assume the question is imperfect. Consequently, getting hung up on the details of a question rather than its _intent_ is misguided, and downvoting even when the OP acknowledges the answer is helpful is just silly.

Comment: @ildjarn Do you judge me ? I have my opinion, you have no right to judge of my vote. Whatever I put my vote a lot before the OP comment so how this could influence my vote ? I still think the answer is not good, point. I say why so please unless you give the some reason like a meta post with an answer approved by the community about this kind of situation who will said that I shouldn't down vote this question. I will reconsidered. But I don't think that you could find that.

Comment: @Stargateur : I'm telling you why everyone is disagreeing with you and why yours is the only downvote. If you _want_ to be contrary, it's your prerogative of course.

Comment: @ildjarn "is just silly", do you insult people frequently when you "I'm telling you why everyone is disagreeing with you" ? Whatever, bye! Plus prove that "everyone is disagreeing with you"

Comment: @ildjarn Maybe you will be surprise but let me learn you something, when 3 people talk to you and tell you "you are wrong" and that you are alone. Yes, this is easy to take it as offense. And 3 is not every one.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. If you link to an allocator, well, just call malloc.
2. The hook into the default global allocator is still unstable, but if you're on nightly, you can call it directly.

On stable Rust today, the closest thing you can get is Vec if you want to use the global allocator, but it's not equivalent for reasons spelled out in other answers.